# Closed due to misunderstanding | How should I translate the sentence with ~のみ

Tags: translation, particles

There is a line in an anime said this:

> でも[高校生]{こうこうせい}**のみ**[運]{うん}ないな。

I understand all the vocabulary in the above line. However, I really don't know which one is indicated by のみ, the high school or luck?

So I try to translate it randomly, in the way I feel most comfortable:

> But, you're only unlucky high school student.

Am I right? Thanks for advance.

Update:
**The context** is a boss having a conversation with a newbie. It happens in workplace for graphic designer, btw. The previous lines of this boss is about how surprised she is when she learn how young her new junior is, just graduating high school.

Comment: This phrase seems to be out of context, and "のみ" rarely appears in daily conversations. Probably you've misheard something...「でも高校生に見えないな」 or something like that. Can you write out the previous lines? And in what episode of what anime did you hear this?

Comment: Yeah, thank you. You are right. Bad ears. I'm going to scroll it for taking your time right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some context would be helpful as it seems a very colloquial expression. Anyway I believe that のみ here refers to the student (since it always follows what it refers to) and I would translate "*...but only high school student(s?) have no luck*".

Splitting it a bit more, it makes me feel of something along the line of "*(the fact of) having no luck is restricted to high school students*". Does that make sense to you, given the context?

However, what seems a bit odd to me is that のみ is usually used in formal speech/writing while the sentence you wrote seems from a casual conversation.

There is some explanation about だけ and のみ [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/amount).

Some context would be helpful as it seems a very colloquial expression. Anyway I believe that のみ here refers to the student (since it always follows what it refers to) and I would translate "*...but only high school student(s?) have no luck*".

Splitting it a bit more, it makes me feel of something along the line of "*(the fact of) having no luck is restricted to high school students*". Does that make sense to you, given the context?

However, what seems a bit odd to me is that のみ is usually used in formal speech/writing while the sentence you wrote seems from a casual conversation.

There is some explanation about だけ and のみ [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/amount).

Big Edit: Thanks to a comment now we know that the sentence was actually:  "高校生にも見えないな" .. That has pretty much nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Thanks.

The context is a boss having a conversation with a newbie. It happens in workplace for graphic designer, btw. The previous lines of this boss is about how surprised she is when she learn how young her new junior is, just graduating high school.

As you said, that conversation pretty informal. But now you mention that 'のみ is usually used in formal speech' then... Could it be an ironic expression?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the sentence is exactly "でも高校生こうこうせいのみ運うんないな"? Just to confirm. About being ironic I would not know, maybe a native speaker could confirm. Anyway, this sentence still seems a bit odd to me (that's why I'm asking a confirmation)

Comment: That is the best I can hear. And I think it can't be miss with the other words. In case you want to clarify yourself, you may wanna watch anime 'New Game!' episode 1 around the time '0:05:49.70' to '0:05:51.43'.

(It confuse me a lot too.)

Comment: Would be good if there were subtitles to check.. At the moment I don't really have the time to check it out, sorry.

Comment: OK, I got it from the official video http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/1467961100 and found that you heard "高校生にも見えないな" I can't see you even as an high school student.

Comment: Ops, thank you @gecko655 and sorry for taking your time, Tommy. So embarrassing.

Comment: Thanks! This makes clear and solves the oddity of the original sentence.